# How catch click on ListPreference like in Android Browser Settings

Tags: android, preferences

The settings of the Android Browser allow to click on a ListPreference if one wants to clear the cache. If the users clicks on that ListPreference no list is shown - a dialog pops up instead.

I would like to use a similar feature to stop a running service.

I created an entry in the application settings without the android:entries and android:entryValues tags:

```
 <ListPreference
     android:key="list_stop"
     android:title="@string/txt_stopservice" />
```

No I try to catch the click:

```
 listPreferenceServiceStop = (ListPreference) preferenceScreen.findPreference("list_stop");
 listPreferenceServiceStop.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        Tools.showToast(context, "BlaBla");
        return true;
    }

 });
```

If the user clicks on this entry the following error appears:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.

The Android Browser settings don't show values neither.

How do they do that? And is this the correct way to catch the click?

Many thanks in advance.
HJW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a ListPreference? You should use a [`DialogPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/DialogPreference.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never used DialogPreferences before. If you look at the Browser Settings they look identical to ListPreferences. It's working perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :) Glad it worked. Didn't know if maybe you had some particular reason for using a ListPreference instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ListPreference myVar = (ListPreference) findPreference("key you define at xml");

    myVar.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            Toast.makeText( getBaseContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            return true;
        }

    });
```